# Designing parent and child relationship in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design, data-modeling

Need input on data model design

I have **parent_table** as

```
id (PK)
current_version
latest_child_id
```

**child_table** as

```
id (PK)
parent_table_id (FK to parent)
version (running number . largest number implies latest child record)
```

The relationship between parent_table to child_table is 1:m .
The parent_table in addition keeps a pointer to the latest version of the record in child table.

The system will insert n mutable rows into the child_table and update the parent_table to point to the latest version- for faster reads.

**My question is:**

1. Is it a bad practice to have the parent_table store the latest
   version of the child table ?
2. Am I looking at potential performance
       problems \ locking issues ? since any insert into the child 
   table-needs a lock on the parent table as well ?

**Database in question:** MySQL

Comment: What is the attribute linking the child to the parent? What determines "latest" in the child table?

Comment: @NevilleKuyt - oops ! I fixed the child_table and added explanation.

Answer (score 2):

*Is it a bad practice to have the parent_table store the latest version of the child table ?*

Phrases like "bad practice" are loaded with context. I much prefer to consider the trade-offs, and understand the decision at that level.
By storing an attribute which you could otherwise calculate, you're undertaking [denormalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormalization). This is an established way of dealing with performance challenges - but it's only one of several. The trade-offs are roughly as follows.

- Negative: takes more storage space. Assume this doesn't matter
- Negative: requires more code. More code means more opportunity for bugs. Consider wrapping the data access code in a test suite.
- Negative: denormalized schemas can require additional "brain space" - you have to remember that you calculate (for instance) the number of children a parent has, but find the latest one by looking at the attribute in the parent table. In an ideal world, a normalized schema describes the business context without having to remember implementation details.
- Negative: may make your data model harder to extend in future. As you add more entities and attributes, this denormalized table may become harder and harder to keep in sync. One denormalized column is usually easy to work with, but if you have lots of denormalized columns, keeping them all up to date may be very difficult.
- Negative: for data that is not accessed often, the denormalized design may be a bigger performance hit than calculating on the fly. Your question 2 is an example of this. In complex scenarios, it's possible that multiple threads create inconsistencies in the denormalized data.
- Positive: with data that is read often, and where the calculation is expensive, a denormalized schema will allow faster read access.

In your case, I doubt you need to store this data as a denormalized attribute. By creating an index on `parent_table_id, version DESC`, retrieving this data on the fly will be too fast to measure (assuming your database holds 10s of millions of records, not 10s of billions).

In general, I recommend only denormalizing if:

- You can prove you have a performance problem (i.e. you have measured it)
- You cannot improve performance by creating better indexes
- You cannot improve performance through better hardware

*Am I looking at potential performance problems \ locking issues ? since any insert into the child table-needs a lock on the parent table as well ?*

As @TheImpaler writes, *probably* not. However, it depends on the complexity of your insert logic (does it do any complicated calculations which might slow things down?), and the likelihood of several concurrent threads trying to update the parent record. You may also end up with inconsistent data in these scenarios.

Answer (score 2):

```
ORDER BY child_id DESC LIMIT 1
```

Is a very efficient way to get the "latest" child (assuming you have `INDEX(child_id)`).

This eliminates the need for the naughty "redundant" info you are proposing.

Answer (score 1):

> 1. Is it a bad practice to have the parent_table store the latest version of the child table ?

No, that's perfectly OK, if it fits the requirements of your application. You need to add the extra logic to update the tables correctly, but that's it. Databases offer you a range of possibilities to store your data and relationships, and this is a perfectly good one.

> 2. Am I looking at potential performance problems \ locking issues ? since any insert into the child table-needs a lock on the parent table as well ?

It depends on how often you are updating/inserting/deleting children. Most likely it's not going to be a problem, unless the rate of changes is above 200+ per second, considering current database servers. Exclusive locking can become a problem for high volume of transactions.

Normally the locks will be at the row level. That it, they will lock only the row you are working with, so multiple threads with different parents will not create a bottleneck.

If your system really requires high level of transactions (1000+ / second), then the options I see are:

- Throw more hardware at it: The easiest way. Just buy a bigger machine and problem solved... at least for a while, until your system grows again.
- Use Optimistic Locking: this strategy doesn't require you to perform any actual lock at all. However, you'll need to add an extra numeric column to store the version number of the row.
- Switch to another database: MySQL may not handle really high volume perfectly well. If that's the case you can consider PostgreSQL, or even Oracle database, that has surely better caching technology but is also very expensive.